# cURL command line to get embedded files in rss feed?

Tags: curl, rss

I have cURL command line running to get an rss feed on a site that requires a login. 
It downloads the rss.xml file that I want, which is similar to [this](http://www.mininova.org/rss/ubuntu).
Now, how do I download the files linked to in this file?
I tried castget, but the link to the file has a redirect which castget can't handle.

Any help? Is there a way to use cURL to grab the links inside the rss file?
Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't entirely make sense, what is 'inside downloaded'? You will need to give more details if anyone is to help you.

Comment: I've revised the question, does it make sense now? Sorry, I didn't know how to explain the problem very well.

Comment: Your question does make more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -s http://www.mininova.org/rss/ubuntu | xml sel -N atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m './/enclosure' -v '@url' -n | wget -i -
```

- **`curl`** get xml from url
- **`xml`**(`xmlstarlet`) extract enclosure url form xml
- **`wget`** download list of url from stdin

If you don't want to download all links, `wget` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks kev, but the machine I'm running this on doesn't have the xml command, which is rather annoying.

Comment: @pratstercs Do you have `grep`? Is your system Windows or Linux?

Comment: I do have grep. It's a Netgear Stora, which (I think) runs plain Unix so has very few commands, grep being one.

Comment: [On Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xmlstarlet) the binary of [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is `xmlstarlet` (`dpkg -L xmlstarlet | grep bin`)